# Swipe to Delete UITableViewCell3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have implemented Swipe to delete for UITableViewCell. Everything is working fine. Now when I swipe to delete, it hides or moves text to left side. I want to restrict this. Cell text should not get hidden on swipe, please help if its possible

Before Swipe

[image]

After Swipe

[image]

Comment: can you please provide the screenshot of your cell before and after swipe?

Comment: the cell text itmeqqq moves on left side after swipe. I dont want to hide it. is it possible?

Comment: may be setting uiedgeinset or content view frame may help you

Comment: So where you want to show the delete button? If your cell doesn't move left then the button will be overlap with your cell content. I don't think which will looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Visit link, addresses the same issue (could be useful)

http://www.drawbackz.com/stack/447520/how-to-stop-cells-from-indenting-shouldindentwhileeditingrowatindexpath-has-no-effect.html